# Empty blank space at the bottom of my site

Tags: wordpress, footer

After installing a plugin at my blog on wordpress.org there's a empty blank space at the bottom of my site, after the footer that i'm unable to locate or remove.

The site is [www.wearethepassengers.com/es](http://www.wearethepassengers.com/es)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as i'm just a not very expert user yet :)

thanks

Comment: are you using wpstats plugin?

Comment: Welcome to SO.   This isn't really a programming question, though... you might find it being closed soon.   However, have you noticed that there is a smiley in the black space?  Is this deliberate?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things which are causing the white space and smiley image in the footer.

1. wpstats - It adds a image at footer. So hide it using CSS.

   ```
   img #wpstats{
       display: none !important;
   }
   ```
2. The social icons on the right hand side has the padding of 5px. So remove the padding:

   ```
   .addthis-smartlayers{
       padding: 0 !important;
   }
   ```

If you check your css code, you have following code:

```
.addthis-smartlayers, div#at4-share, div#at4-follow, div#at4-whatsnext, div#at4-thankyou {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Change this to:

```
.addthis-smartlayers, div#at4-share, div#at4-follow, div#at4-whatsnext, div#at4-thankyou {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This would solve your issue.

Comment: Wow! Yes i added the css code in order to match the social icons on the right to my search button bar, i couldn't imagine it was the cause. Amazing thanks so much for your quick response :)

Comment: I am glad that it worked. If answer is correct, please mark it as correct answer or upvote it.